# In Sutton-Barto a confusing point regarding $\epsilon$-soft policies in the proof for optimality of MC control without exploring starts

Tags: reinforcement-learning, sutton-barto

Sutton-Barto, page 102:

In the second paragraph, we have:

> Consider a new environment that is just like the original environment,
> except with the requirement that policies be $\epsilon$-soft “moved
> inside” the environment."

Later in this paragraph, it is written as:

> The best one can do in this new environment with general policies is
> the same as the best one could do in the original environment with
> $\epsilon$-soft policies.

Is there an inconsistency between the two statements because if we are allowed general policies in the new environment why do we need the requirement of $\epsilon$-soft policies “moved inside” the new environment?

Answer (score 1):

He's trying to turn the requirement "this policy is $\epsilon$-soft" into a feature of the environment. That way every policy in the new environment could be turned into an $\epsilon$-soft in the old.

Comment: But if  we are allowed general policies in the new environment  why do we need this requirement because general policies include $epsilon$-soft policies?

Comment: The point of $\epsilon$-soft policies is to encourage exploration (important for finding good policies; I think it can be shown that training an RL agent w/ $\epsilon$-soft policies will be exponentially more likely to converge to the highest-reward policy). The point of making a *new* environment is so he doesn't need to put this requirement on the policy anymore.